# remove focus from JTable first row

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtable

I have JTable and rows in it. By default first row is selected and focus is in it. How can I deselect first row and change focus to somewhere else that `.addListener(new RowSetListener()` will work in first row too.

I already try:

```
tableZaposlenciView1.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);        
//tableZaposlenciView1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
//tableZaposlenciView1.setColumnSelectionInterval(0,0);
//tableZaposlenciView1.setRowSelectionInterval(false,false);        
tableZaposlenciView1.changeSelection(0,0,false,false);
tableZaposlenciView1.requestFocus();
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Well, if you want to change to something OTHER than (0,0), maybe you shouldn't use (0,0) as arguments to changeSelection(), am I right?

Comment: i can try 12, 2 but is the same

Comment: changeSelection(...) works perfectly fine for me. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem. We can't keep guessing what you may or may not be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone else have similar problem with ADF and JTable here is solution. I achieve that by overriding first() on the VO impl. my problem can be solved.

That comes in handy in many situations:

- no selection after refresh (just return null from first())
- reselect a particular row after refresh (before refresh, store a row key, after refresh in first() if stored key is found, navigate to that row and return that from first())
- find next matching row for user to work on after refresh of a worklist
- avoid costly detail executions in a VL situation

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at JTable's changeSelection() method. I believe it does what you want.

EDIT: If you want to *clear* the selection:

```
JTable table = ...;
table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
```

Comment: i try tableZaposlenciView1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

Comment: and also with tableZaposlenciView1.requestFocus() but first row is always selected and listener on first row not working. I have no more ideas...

Comment: i also try to add focus on some other component like  boolean check = panelTabi.requestFocusInWindow(); but check is always false

Comment: +1 Using `clearSelection()` works in `ListSelectionDemo`,  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/index.html#ListSelectionDemo